# Rewriting multiple git repos into one

Tags: git

I have three unrelated repositories which I'd like to rewrite into a single repository, by moving each repo to a different subdir. I'm doing something like this:

`` some_url=git@github.com/blah/"
repos='a b c d e f g'
git init
git commit --allow-empty -m 'Unified repo base commit'
for repo in $repos; do
    git fetch $some_url/$repo
    git checkout -b rewrite-$repo
    # prefix commit messages with original repo name
    git filter-branch -f --msg-filter "/bin/echo -n '${repo}: ' && cat"
    # the rewrite just does `mv * $repo/` for all files in each $repo
    git filter-branch -f --tree-filter "mkdir -p ${repo}; find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name ${repo} | -exec -- mv '{}' ${repo} ';'"
    git checkout master
    # rebase the rewritten branch in
    git rebase rewrite-$repo
done ``

However, I get merge conflicts on the rebase. As far as I can tell these conflicts are not within the different repos, but when rewinding the history for a single repos. It almost looks like patches are not applied in the right order (e.g. at the point of conflict the file is in a different state than it was at in the original repo just before that commit).

I fail to understand how this can happen -- naively, since all the repos have been rewritten to use different subdirs there seems no potential for an overlap and rewinding on rebase ought not change anything. I tried an analogous solution with git format-patch and git am to import, but the same thing happens. Same again when trying to use cpan's `Git::FastExport::Stitch`.

I eventually settled for doing a repeated normal merge of all the repos (irritatingly, it does not seem possible to do an octopus merge if there is no common ancestor), but I'd still be curious to understand what is going on and how to do this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** - Added a little more about why rebasing through merges can be trouble, plus some other notes based on comments

---

My guess would be that the individual repos' histories are not strictly linear (i.e. there were branch and merge points)?  If so, `rebase` can be expected to make a mess of that (see below).  Rebasing the entirety of any non-trivial history is usually a bad idea.

If you really want to impose a (seemingly arbitrary) linear order to the additions of projects to the repo, you'll probably need to do some more `filter-branch` work.  Given

```
A --- B --- C <--(repo1)

D --- E --- F <--(repo2)
 \        /
  G ---- H
```

you could `filter-branch` on `repo2`, using a `tree-filter` to add the sub-directory from `C` plus a `parent-filter` to graft `D` onto `C`.  Repeat for each repo.

If you want the octopus merge, root the repo branches on an empty "initial commit" (which you'll create with `commit --allow-empty`) instead of rooting each one independently.  (But of course that's not an option if you need to preserve commmit ID's; in that case getting an octopus merge is at best much more difficult.)

Getting back to why rebase can be a problem: Basically there are two problems.

First, at most it moves a single branch head.  If you have other refs (tags, multiple branches) you'll have to move them separately.  (I'd say "manually", but if there are many of them you could find a way to script them...  But the "obvious" solution - running multiple rebase operations - doesn't do what you'd want.)

More importantly, it doesn't handle merges all that well.  By default it wants to produce a linear history, and it just seems to have trouble keeping track of what it's doing when it goes back for the "other side" of a merge.

You can fix about 80% of the problem with rebasing through merges by specifying `--preserve-merges`, which attempts to prune-and-graft the subtree "as it is" rather than linearlizing the history within the subtree.  But if the merge wasn't done 100% automatically by the default merge strategy, one of two things will happen:

If you're lucky, when rebase tries to redo the merge it will fail with conflicts and you'll be consulted to redo the conflict resolution (which, of course, may have been done by someone else, or whatever, but at least you're getting the chance to fix it).  The worst case is that the merge doesn't fail with conflicts, but still isn't right (either because the original merge was done with edits via `--no-commit`, or was done with other than the default merge strategy leading to a different result).  In that case `rebase` won't know it isn't right and will silently go on, with your history broken.

For that reason, if you do ever rebase a non-trivial history, you'll likely have to use `--preserve-merges` *and* thoroughly validate the final result, e.g. by comparing the new subtree with the old one commit by commit.  (That isn't always easy, but in your case it would just be comparison of a particular subtree so would at least be doable.)

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it is related to the history not being linear. But can you explain exactly how this causes problems? After all, no textual content changed and non of the different repos touch the same paths.

Comment: Concerning rooting on empty "inital commit" do you mean 
```git commit -m 'root' --allow-empty; git merge --allow-unrelated-histories a b c``` or do you mean rebasing each repo, so that for every repo each branch has the same empty commit as ultimate ancestor? The downside with that is that you lose the main benefit of merging rather than rebasing, that your commit ids don't change.

Comment: If the history within a repo is non-linear, then rebase could encounter trouble within that repo - so whether the repos overlap really wouldn't be a factor. I was considering the main advantage of rebasing instead of merging to be "it works", but if you also are getting value out of preserving the commit ID's, then you're correct - getting an octopus would at best be very difficult. (I suspect you could still do it by abusing `parent-filter`s in `git filter-branch`.)